# PKCS#11 provider in OpenSSH: Is it possible to cache PIN?

Tags: linux, openssh, key-authentication, smartcard, caching

I use a RSA key on a smartcard with an OpenSSH client. The smartcard is read by a smartcard reader with a pinpad. The key is protected with a PIN.

Is it possible to cache the PIN somehow? I don't really like the need to write the PIN using the card reader keyboard every time I use ssh... It's not only annoying but it also makes IMHO too many possibilities for other people's eyes.

My setup is Debian/Devuan + OpenSC + the typical "PKCS11Provider /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/opensc-pkcs11.so" in .ssh/config.

I tried to add to opensc.conf, framework pkcs15 following lines, but with no effect:

```
use_pin_caching = true;
pin_cache_counter = 64;
pin_cache_ignore_user_consent = true;
```

I use the same configuration on OpenBSD, and it's the same.

As a smart card I use Aventra MyEID 4.5.5. As I am trying to learn as much as possible before using the technology in production, I have different card readers I can try: Cherry, Gemalto (now Thales) and SCM/Identiv.

Comment: In general, no: the PIN is the 2nd factor with having the card. However, some commercial grade SC allow for certain conveniences, so: make, model, and versionnof your SC?

Comment: I will add the info by edit. THX! I keep on being suprised, how diverse and "unspecified on purpose" the world of PKCS is.

Answer (score 1):

`ssh-agent` will cache the PIV credential for a set period of time (via `-t` in ssh-agent or ssh-add).

Since your ssh client is already able to successfully authenticate with your smartcard/piv, these `ssh-add` command will likely do the trick of caching it in ssh-agent for you:

```
ssh-add -s <path to shared library pkcs11>  #add keys provided by pkcs11
#          for me, /usr/lib/ssh-keychain.dylib
```

When the cached identity has expired, the ssh error is:

> `sign_and_send_pubkey: signing failed for RSA "`*`<id>`*`" from agent: agent refused operation`

Then, you clear the old cache entry with:

```
ssh-add -e <path to shared library pkcs11>  #removed keys provided by pkcs11
#          again, for me, /usr/lib/ssh-keychain.dylib

ssh-add -D                                  #delete all identities from agent (may not be needed, ymmv)
```

See `man ssh-add` for further details, though there aren't any other PIV-specific options other than -s and -e as of Feb 2024.

One caveat is that you are using pkcs15; I'm not sure on the interoperability with `ssh-add`/`ssh-agent`, but in you pass in the right library, that might be all in needs.